# How to add more then 10 columns with SwiftUI Table. Xcode 13.0 Beta 5 + Mac OS 12.1 Beta

Tags: xcode, macos, swiftui

Just wanna try to use new feature Table in SwiftUI, but only can add 10 columns, not sure what I can do to add more columns with this Table feature. Any comments will be much appreciated.

:-> Xcode 13.0 Beta 5 + Mac OS 12.1 Beta

import SwiftUI

```
struct Person: Identifiable {
    let givenName: String
    let familyName: String
    let id = UUID()
}

private var people = [
    Person(givenName: "Juan", familyName: "Chavez"),
    Person(givenName: "Mei", familyName: "Chen"),
    Person(givenName: "Tom", familyName: "Clark"),
    Person(givenName: "Gita", familyName: "Kumar"),
]

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Table(people) {
            TableColumn("Column1", value: \.givenName)
            TableColumn("Column2", value: \.familyName)
            TableColumn("Column3", value: \.givenName)
            TableColumn("Column4", value: \.familyName)
            TableColumn("Column5", value: \.givenName)
            TableColumn("Column6", value: \.familyName)
            TableColumn("Column7", value: \.givenName)
            TableColumn("Column8", value: \.familyName)
            TableColumn("Column9", value: \.givenName)
            TableColumn("Column10", value: \.familyName)
            TableColumn("Column11", value: \.givenName)
            TableColumn("Column12", value: \.familyName)
            
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you Group {} ten columns and use multiple Groups?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I tried, but it doesn't work, won't complied successfully...

Comment: It seems like you are repeating a pattern. Put them in a ForEach loop

Comment: Tried, doesn't work, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the grouping to work however there is a limitation in swiftUI. You can only declare 10 subviews inside of a view.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    private var people = [
        Person(givenName: "Juan", familyName: "Chavez"),
        Person(givenName: "Mei", familyName: "Chen"),
        Person(givenName: "Tom", familyName: "Clark"),
        Person(givenName: "Gita", familyName: "Kumar"),
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Group {
                Table(people) {
                    TableColumn("Column1", value: \.givenName)
                    TableColumn("Column2", value: \.familyName)
                    TableColumn("Column3", value: \.givenName)
                    TableColumn("Column4", value: \.familyName)
                    TableColumn("Column5", value: \.givenName)
                    TableColumn("Column6", value: \.familyName)
                    TableColumn("Column7", value: \.givenName)
                    TableColumn("Column8", value: \.familyName)
                    TableColumn("Column9", value: \.givenName)
                    TableColumn("Column10", value: \.familyName)
                }
            }
            Group {
                Table(people) {
                    TableColumn("Column1", value: \.givenName)
                    TableColumn("Column2", value: \.familyName)
                    TableColumn("Column3", value: \.givenName)
                    TableColumn("Column4", value: \.familyName)
                    TableColumn("Column5", value: \.givenName)
                    TableColumn("Column6", value: \.familyName)
                    TableColumn("Column7", value: \.givenName)
                    TableColumn("Column8", value: \.familyName)
                    TableColumn("Column9", value: \.givenName)
                    TableColumn("Column10", value: \.familyName)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct Person: Identifiable {
    let givenName: String
    let familyName: String
    let id = UUID()
}
```

This compiles however idk how much you will like it once you see how it compiles in the preview but it does compile.

Comment: Really appreciate your time, thanks, it compiles but still can not figure out how to create more than 10 columns in just ONE Table.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem, ya unfortunately its a limitation in swift.

Comment: Not sure if anyone has any workarounds to make a table more than 10 column. any help will be appreciated.